# c# problem with a specific CMD Command Line

Tags: c#, cmd, command, location, line

I'm having a hard time with executing a CMD command line in C#
(when I copy the command to CMD it works).

The command(the quotation marks is part of the command):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\SolarWinds\Dameware Remote Support\dwrcc.exe" -c: -h: -m:10.10.41.82 -a:1

How I wrote it C#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SolarWinds\\Dameware Remote Support\\dwrcc.exe\" -c: -h: -m:10.10.41.82 -a:1");
```

The Error I get is that the location has not been found.
there is some issue with the brackets or quotation marks I think, but I don't know what.

Comment: The path to the application does not have to be in quotes. The parameters get passed as a second argument to [`Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-6.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_) Example: `Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SolarWinds\Dameware Remote Support\dwrcc.exe", "-c: -h: -m:10.10.41.82 -a:1");`

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it with `@` instead

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SolarWinds\Dameware Remote Support\dwrcc.exe", "-c: -h: -m:10.10.41.82 -a:1");
```

Prefixing the string with `@` indicates that it should be treated as a literal, i.e. no escaping.

So, you can for example if your string contains a path you would typically do this:

```
string path = "c:\\path\\to\\file.txt";
```

Writing it with `@` allows you to write it clearer without needing the double slashes

```
string path = @"c:\path\to\file.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape Unicode characters by preceding the hexadecimal value with "\u". The hexadecimal value of a double quote is 0022, so you can include this in your string.

For example:

quote = "\u0022Alive\u0022, she cried!";